# Where can I add "Trim" to this C# statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm stuck. Where can I add "Trim" to this C# statement? Each line will be a separate file name. But because each file may have space after it, I'd like to trim it off.

```
string[] lines = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\adminkeys.cfg"));
```

Thanks

Comment: Hum, maybe `(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\adminkeys.cfg")).Select(s=> s.Trim());`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are trying to trim each line, then you need to do it line by line, for example, with LINQ:

```
string[] lines = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\adminkeys.cfg"))
    .Select(l => l.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: For .NET 4.0, it would be slightly more efficient to replace `ReadAllLines` with `ReadLines`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx